# View rendering as plain text when action called from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm trying to call a controller action (JsonResult) from within a partial view:

```
var departmentsViewJS = {
    view: "accordion",
    multi: true,
    cols: @Html.Action("GetDepartmentsJson")
};
```

The action is called, and wonderful Json replaces the `@Html.Action` in the output, but the whole view (_Layout, View, and partial) is rendered to the page as plain text.  If I replace the Action with just brackets like so:

```
var departmentsViewJS = {
    view: "accordion",
    multi: true,
    cols: []
};
```

The page renders perfectly fine (but without those cols).  Are we not allowed to do stuff like this in partials, or have I messed up somewhere?

Here's an example of the rendered output:

```
var departmentsViewJS = {
    view: "accordion",
    multi: true,
    cols: [{"Id":25,"DocRoot":"Test","Name":"Test","DepartmentKeywords":null},{"Id":27,"DocRoot":"HumanResources","Name":"Human Resources","DepartmentKeywords":null}]
};
```

If I copy the rendered Json over the `@Html.Action` the page also renders fine.

Comment: is your script on the partial?

Comment: Yes the javascript is in the partial.

Comment: I don't know if that is the cause of your issue but it is highly recommended to not put script in your partial.  It gets inserted into the middle of the page and can cause very weird effects with the script

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with those issues.  I'm working on a somewhat...unorthodox design strategy.  But like I said in the post, the javascript works fine in all cases except when I call the controller action (including when I copy/paste the controller action results in place of the controller action).

Comment: So do you want to call @Html.Action somehow on some action and assign results to cols?

Comment: Yes the rendered output shown in the post is exactly what I want to be in my Html/Javascript, but it's putting the entire document (starting at `<!DOCTYPE html>` and ending at `</html>`) inside of a <pre> tag and displaying the whole thing as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you call action which return JsonResult it set response content type to application/json.

You can change return type of your GetDepartmentsJson to string and serialize your object to json on server side.

If you do not want to change your controller than you can do changes on your view

```
@{ var prevContentType = Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType; }

var departmentsViewJS = {
   view: "accordion",
   multi: true,
   cols: @Html.Action("GetDepartmentsJson"); }
};

@{ Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = prevContentType; }
```

Comment: Another brilliant design decision by the MVC team. Means that functions that return JsonResult can *only* be cleanly called using ajax.